# Order objects List items

Tags: c#

In my app I have array of objects. Each object contains `List` with urls. I want to display `Lists` item in that order:

```
First item from first objects list
First item from second objects list
First item from third objects list
Second item from first objects list
..
etc
```

Right now I am using `foreach` loop:

```
            foreach (Account acc in account)
            {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(acc.ShowData())
            }
```

And public method inside `Account` class to get items:

```
public string ShowData()
{          
        string singleItem = LinksArray.First();
        LinksArray.RemoveAt(0);
        return singleItem;               
}
```

It works, but I think there might be more elegant way to do this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Probably better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try flattening everything into an set of index/URL pairs, then order by index:

```
var orderedUrls = objects
    .SelectMany(o => o.Urls.Select((url, idx) => new { Index = idx, Url = url }))
    .OrderBy(indexedUrl => indexedUrl.Index)
    .Select(indexedUrl => indexedUrl.Url)
```

Comment: Must be a good solution if two people come up with it within 30-odd seconds of each other. I like your naming convention better and the use of `SelectMany` is a bit cleaner than `Select`/`Concat`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
List<Uri>[] arrayOfListsOfUris = ...

IEnumerable<Uri> sorted =
    arrayOfListsOfUris
        .Select(xs => xs.Select((x, n) => new { x, n }))
        .Concat()
        .OrderBy(y => y.n)
        .Select(y => y.x);

foreach (Uri uri in sorted)
{
    //Do something with each Uri
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method named `ShowData` should never modify the data it is showing. Instead, you might be better served by something like this;

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetData()
{
    return LinksArray;
}
```

Which you can then use;

```
foreach(Account acc in accounts)
{
    foreach(String data in acc.GetData())
    {
        // add to listbox items
    }
}
```

This keeps a clear separation between your data and the way it's displayed and read by consumers of the class. It also, optionally, opens you up to using LINQ.